# change output format of chr to hexadecimal

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have

```
print [chr 0x49, chr 0x9f]
```

which outputs

```
"I\159"
```

How do I make `print` use hexadecimal numbers when it prints characters that have to be shown as escape sequences? So that my output reads:

```
"I\x9f"
```

Comment: This question seems slightly confused. `chr` returns a `Char`; it knows nothing about hex or escape sequences.

Comment: That is, the output you are asking about is that of `print`, which just uses the `Show` instance of `Char`.

Comment: yes, of course. a typo. fixed. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't change it.

`print x` is the same as `putStrLn (show x)` and you can't change the way `show` works for types which already have a Show instance defined.

You can, however, define you own formatting functions:

```
fmtChar :: Char -> String
fmtChar ch = ...

fmtString :: String -> String
fmtString s = "\"" ++ (concatMap fmtChar s) ++ "\""
```

and use them where you want to see your format:

```
putStrLn $ fmtString [ chr 0x49, chr 0x9f ]
```

One way of defining `fmtChar`:

```
import Numeric (showHex)

fmtChar ch =
  if length s == 1
    then s
    else "\\x" ++ showHex (fromEnum ch) ""
  where s = show ch
```

(Note: `Numeric` is in `base` so you already have it.)